# Getting displacement from the accelerometer data for vertical motion

Tags: filters, butterworth, numerical-algorithms

I have an accelerometer sensor with gyro and need to figure out the vertical displacement from the acceleration data. The device that contains the accelerometer will move up and down in fairly consistent cycles (kind of like oscillating motion but not really). The force that is being applied to the device will stay mostly constant. From my surface level research I have found that there are basic ways like calibration routines, moving average filters and butterworth filters to correct the drift in sensor data and also numerical integration techniques like Simpson's rule and the Trapezoid rule. However, I don't quite understand how these things fit together. What exactly is drift and how is it corrected by subtracting the mean? What is the function of a butterworth filter? What are ways to reduce rounding/floating point errors in the integration process? How do I integrate all of these techniques into a robust solution? I understand that displacement is acceleration integrated twice, but I'm clueless on the signal processing part. If anyone could help me out on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello lemonade5117 and welcome to Signal Processing. Your question is quite broad. You are asking a lot of stuff at the same time and it won't be very easy for someone to help you solve your problem without putting a lot of effort into writing a lengthy answer. I suggest you, at minimum reformat your question to make each question clearly visible so that it will be easier for other contributors to try an address each "subproblem" in a concise way.

Comment: First, because of the planet under the room, this is a "you can't get there from here" problem in general.  _If_ this cyclical motion you're talking about is always along the same path, such that the average vertical position and average vertical velocity are always zero _then_ you can do this -- but you need to _edit your question_ to say that's the case.  Second, while you're editing, _trim out all the other questions_, and just concentrate on presenting the problem you're trying to solve, and asking how to solve it.